# Using JS, how do I swap out a specifc instance of text instead of all instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this is a really noobish question but I have just made a form with sections that are toggle-able. Each section has a '.header' which on click will perform a slideToggle on the section div.

I would like to add a triangle either pointing down or sideways to let people know it is toggle-able. (i.e ▶ or ▼).

I have the triangle in a span with the class '.arrowTog'
I was able to get partial success with

```
  $('.header').on('click', function() {
      if ($('.arrowTog').text().contains('▼')){
          $('.arrowTog').text('▶');
      }else{
          $('.arrowTog').text('▼');
      }
  });
```

When I clicked on one all of the triangles swapped so I tried this (which causes none of them to rotate at all):

```
 $('.header').on('click', function() {
     if ($(this).prev('.arrowTog').text().contains('▼')){
         $(this).prev('.arrowTog').text('▶');
     }else{
         $(this).prev('.arrowTog').text('▼');
     }
 });
```

This is a sample of the HTML

```
     <div class="header" style="cursor: pointer;">
         <span class="arrowTog">&#9654;&nbsp;</span>
         <b>Merchant</b>
     </div>
     <div class="searchContent" style="display:none;">
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Some tips: Don't add comments to your question. Just update the question instead. Do not say things like "it does not work". Instead, think like a programmer and tell us exactly what it's doing that is unexpected, and what you've figured out about that so far.

Comment: `.arrowTog` is _inside_ `.header`, not _next_ to it. Use `find` or `children` instead of `prev`.

Comment: You can pass the element that called the function to the function - then you can get the id of that element and process like that.

Comment: And don’t forget to add the `&nbsp;` to the `text` methods in your jQuery code.

Comment: @Xufox thanks good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version, the problem is you're finding *every* `.arrowTog` in the page.  You can use the fact that within the click handler, `this` is bound to the element that was clicked, and then just search within that using [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('.header').on('click', function() {
  var arrow = $(this).find('.arrowTog');
  if (arrow.text().contains('▼')){
    arrow.text('▶');
  } else {
    arrow.text('▼');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly. So .find searches other part of same div?

Comment: Given an element (the `.header` that was clicked on in this case), `find` will look only at the child elements of that element.  It's explained in full on the API page that I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a class. You probably have a number of elements with the same class in it, so jQuery is matching all of them and doing this transformation to all of them.

Use a context (All .arrowTog RIGHT INSIDE THIS NODE): 

    `$('.header').on('click', function(evt) {
    if ($('.arrowTog', evt.target).text().contains('▼')){
    $('.arrowTog', evt.target).text('▶');
    }else{
    $('.arrowTog', evt.target).text('▼');
    }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS?

```
.arrowTog:before {
    content: '▶';
}
.arrowTog.open:before {
    content: '▼';
}
```

And then

```
$('.header').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```